# Avro Python from CSV - avro.io.AvroTypeException: The datum is not an example of the schema

Tags: python, avro

I'm a newbie to Avro.  I'm trying to parse a simple CSV file containing one string value and one int value, but I'm getting the error: **avro.io.AvroTypeException: The datum is not an example of the schema**

The schema I'm using is:

```
{"namespace": "paymenttransaction",
 "type": "record",
 "name": "Payment",
 "fields": [
     {"name": "TransactionId", "type": "string"},
     {"name": "Id",  "type": "int"}
 ]
}
```

The CSV file has the content:

```
TransactionId,Id
2018040101000222749,1
```

And the Python code that I am running for the producer is:

```
from confluent_kafka import avro
from confluent_kafka.avro import AvroProducer
import csv

value_schema = avro.load('/home/daniela/avro/example.avsc')

AvroProducerConf = {'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092',
                    'schema.registry.url': 'http://localhost:8081',
                    }

avroProducer = AvroProducer(AvroProducerConf, default_value_schema=value_schema)

with open('/home/usertest/avro/data/paymenttransactions.csv') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file, delimiter=",")
    for row in reader:

        avroProducer.produce(topic='test', value=row)
        print(row)
        avroProducer.flush()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because Id is still a string and schema requires an int.

Try with :

```
with open('/home/usertest/avro/data/paymenttransactions.csv') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file, delimiter=",")
    for row in reader:
        data_set = {"TransactionId": row["TransactionId"], "Id": int(row["Id"])}
        avroProducer.produce(topic='test', value=data_set)
        print(row)
        avroProducer.flush()
```